# Aligning floated DIVs in a flexible container

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have a set of left floated DIVs inside of flexible container (part #1), when container is resized in a way that it can't contain all of the DIVs in a single row instead of default behavior (2) I want the rows to be perfectly aligned maintaining spaces where needed (table-like behavior), as shown in part #3.

Is it possible to accomplish this using CSS and HTML alone?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your #2 image is **not** what happens when elements are left-floated. You can see an example of what *will* happen on [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g2s3t/).

And if you're interested in [the reason](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#floats):

> A floated box is shifted to the left or right until its outer edge touches the containing block edge or the outer edge of another float. If there is a line box, the outer top of the floated box is aligned with the top of the current line box.

If you know in advance how wide the container is going to be, you can set every `:nth-child()` to have `clear:left` to display in a row.

in the fiddle, you can add:

```
div:nth-child(3n)
{
  clear: left;
}
```

In the css and everything will be aligned properly. The issue will be if you want a fluid layout with auto-adjusting rows. You'll need to use JavaScript to adjust the styles on the elements on resize.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about this nth-child stuff. I'll experiment with this and perhaps I'll be able to combine this with width related media queries in a way that for some range depending on container width the N will be changed based on query expression.

Comment: it's only supported in modern browsers, i.e. not IE.

Comment: Still will work for me. I'll use this in my own project where I've already decided to drop support for IE lower then 9.

Answer (score 0):

First thing that comes to mind is to wrap every box in a uniformly sized div that does the floating, and which has a transparent background.

Answer (score 0):

For this to work, you would have to know the height for your biggest div.  If this is dynamic and you can't control or predict the height then I dont think this will work.

Essentially, wrap each of the divs in another div and set the min-height property to that of the biggest div you expect to see.

This should produce #3.

Also check out the min-height hack for IE 7 - [Min-Height Fast Hack](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBkQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dustindiaz.com%2Fmin-height-fast-hack%2F&rct=j&q=ie7%20min-height%20hack&ei=n8M5TY_uJZO7hAf38NmJCg&usg=AFQjCNG63H9SqZqBhQ6UNIA_Ep0H5qLf4A&sig2=ZdKbQpXG9j-uiA6EYoQezw&cad=rja)

Comment: As far as I understand for this to work I'll have to use JS to find a biggest DIV in each "row" after every resize?

Comment: If you don't already know or can predict the biggest height.  Otherwise I think javascript will be the only way. 

If you know the height of your largest div, simply apply the min-height property in your CSS to a div that wraps them.